# Calling a function multiple times with return value

Tags: function, python-3.x, dictionary, return-value, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *

def draw():
    returnStuff = {'again' : 0, '1st' : 1 }

    draw.again = False
    win = GraphWin("Quadrilateral Maker", 600, 600)
    win.setBackground("yellow")
    text = Text(Point(150, 15), 'Click 4 points to create a Quadrilateral')
    text.draw(win)

    #gets the 4 points 
    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p3 = win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)
    p4 = win.getMouse()
    p4.draw(win)
    vertices = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

    #draws the shape
    quad = Polygon(vertices)
    quad.setFill('red')
    quad.setOutline('black')
    quad.setWidth(3)
    quad.draw(win)

    text.setText('Click in the appropriate box.')

    #Quit box
    quitBox = Rectangle(Point(30, 500), Point(100,550))
    quitBox.setFill('green')
    quitBox.draw(win)
    quitorNah = Text(Point(60, 490), 'Quit')
    quitorNah.draw(win)

    #again box
    quitBox = Rectangle(Point(480, 500), Point(550,550))
    quitBox.setFill('green')
    quitBox.draw(win)
    quitorNah = Text(Point(510, 490), 'Draw Again')
    quitorNah.draw(win)

    click = win.getMouse()
    x = click.getX()
    y = click.getY()

    while True:
        if 30 < x < 100 and 500 < y < 550:
            returnStuff['again'] = 0
            win.close()
            break


        elif 480 < x < 550 and 500 < y < 550:
            returnStuff['again'] = 1
            win.close()
            break

    return returnStuff


count = 1
returnValue = draw()

if returnValue['1st'] == 1:
    count = 0

while count == 1 or returnValue['again'] == 1:
    return_value = draw()
```

So  I have this simple interactive program using Zelle graphics, it asks the user to click on 4 points in a window and from that it creates a shape. Then, the user is shown 2 boxes, one to quit and one to draw again. My draw again isn't working, and it has something to do with the return value. I am returning a dictionary, as I need access to 2 of the variables within the function. In the 'returnStuff' dictionary, I have a part called 'again', which is initially set to 0. If the user clicks in the run again box, it changes this value to 1, and then outside the function I have an if statement that should call the function again if that again value is 1. It does this properly the FIRST time, but the 2nd time around my program just stops all together, and I don't understand why.

Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a while...

```
while count==1 or returnValue['again'] == 1:
    returnValue = draw()
```

Comment: alright i changed the last if statement at the bottom into a while, and then if they click the quit box i set the 'again' to 0 incase they want to quit after they repeat the program once. But now it is infinetly looping, like if i click draw again once, it will keep repeating regardless of which option i pick?

Comment: you need to reset return_value (as i have above)

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything

Comment: ooops...set returnValue = draw().. The one you're checking in the while

Comment: Ah, i see, so you have to restate the variable for the return value every time?